# Scrapy not scraping links gathered from pagination

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape an e-commerce website for its products, and I am currently facing an issue that not all of the pages I get with pagination are visited. The links themselves are valid, and visitable, not non-existing.

My spider code:

```
import scrapy
import json
from pbl.items import ShopCard

class SpidermaximaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spiderMaxima'
    allowed_domains = ['www.trobos.lt']
    start_urls = ['https://trobos.lt/prekes?vendor=MAXIMA']
    item = []
    list = [{
        'sid': 10,
        'name': 'Maxima',
        'domain': 'hhttps://www.maxima.lt/',
        'imageurl': 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c1/Maxima_logo.svg',
        'product': item
        }]

    def __init__(self):
        self.declare_xpath()

    def declare_xpath(self):
        self.getAllItemsXpath =  '//*[@id="category"]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/a/@href'
        self.TitleXpath  = '//*[@id="product"]/section[1]/div[3]/section/div[2]/h1/text()'    
        self.PriceXpath = '//*[@id="product"]/section[1]/div[3]/section/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span/text()'

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath(self.getAllItemsXpath):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url,callback=self.parse_main_item, dont_filter=True)

        next_page = [response.url + '&page='+str(x) for x in range(1,193)]
        for page in next_page:
            print('-'* 100)
            print(page)
            print('-'* 100)
            url = page
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)
     
    def parse_main_item(self,response): 
        shop = ShopCard()
        Title = response.xpath(self.TitleXpath).extract_first()
        Link = response.url
        Image = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c1/Maxima_logo.svg'
        Price = response.xpath(self.PriceXpath).extract_first()
        Price = Price.replace(',', '.')
        Price = float(Price.split(' ')[0])

        shop['item'] = {
                'title': Title,
                'link': Link,
                'image': Image,
                'price': Price
            }

        self.item.append(shop['item'])
 
    def closed(self, reason):
        with open("spiderMaxima.json", "w") as final:
            json.dump(self.list, final, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```

I am using a list with range() function, because in the response (from scrapy shell view(response), pagination buttons are connected to a script.
I have also tried scrapy shell several of the links, the outputs for xpaths work, but still, the pages are not getting scraped. What may be the issue? Are there other ways to deal with the pagination?

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with your code, and other things that can be improved. Please read the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html) carefully.

1. There's really no need to create xpath attributes.
2. You can write the xpath way shorter.
3. You can create a `start_urls` from the beginning.
4. You can let the `item exporter` to handle the json.

Here's an example, change it to your needs.

```py
import scrapy


class ShopCard(scrapy.Item):
    item = scrapy.Field()


class SpidermaximaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spiderMaxima'
    allowed_domains = ['trobos.lt']
    start_urls = [f'https://trobos.lt/prekes?vendor=MAXIMA&page={i}' for i in range(1, 190)]
    items = []
    
    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.4,
        'FEEDS': {
            'spiderMaxima.json': {
                'format': 'json',
                'indent': 2,
                }
        }
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        for url in response.xpath('//div[@class="card small"]//a[contains(@class, "shrink")]/@href').getall():
            yield response.follow(url=url, callback=self.parse_main_item)

    def parse_main_item(self, response):
        shop = ShopCard()
        Title = response.xpath('//h1/text()').get()
        Link = response.url
        Image = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c1/Maxima_logo.svg'
        Price = response.xpath('//div[@class="price"]//span/text()').get()
        Price = Price.replace(',', '.')
        Price = float(Price.split(' ')[0])

        shop['item'] = {
            'title': Title,
            'link': Link,
            'image': Image,
            'price': Price
        }

        yield shop
```